# Docx4j Footer not showing in MS-Word 2016

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I am creating a docx file using DOCx4j Library in Java. I have created the Footer which is showing perfectly in Libra Office but it is not showing in MS-Word 2016.

**Footer Code:**

```
    public static Relationship createFooterPageNumPart(
                WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage) throws Exception {

           FooterPart footerPart = new FooterPart();
              MainDocumentPart t = wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

            footerPart.setPackage(wordprocessingMLPackage);
        //  footerPart.setJaxbElement(createFooterWithPageNr());

            footerPart.setJaxbElement(createFooterWithPageNr(wordprocessingMLPackage,footerPart));
            return t.addTargetPart(footerPart);
        }




       public static Ftr createFooterWithPageNr(WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage, Part sourcePart) throws Exception {
            Ftr ftr = objectFactory.createFtr();
            P paragraph = objectFactory.createP();
            RPr fontRPr = getRPr(objectFactory, "Frutiger LT Arabic 45 Light", "000000", "20", STHint.EAST_ASIA,
                    false, false, false, false);
            R run = objectFactory.createR();
            run.setRPr(fontRPr);
            paragraph.getContent().add(run);

            setParagraphAlign(objectFactory, paragraph, JcEnumeration.RIGHT);
            ftr.getContent().add(paragraph);
            return ftr;
        }

 public static void createFooterReference(
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage,
            Relationship relationship)
            throws InvalidFormatException {

        List<SectionWrapper> sections = wordprocessingMLPackage
                .getDocumentModel().getSections();
        SectPr sectPr = sections.get(sections.size() - 1).getSectPr();
        // There is always a section wrapper, but it might not contain a sectPr
        if (sectPr == null) {
            sectPr = objectFactory.createSectPr();
             wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(sectPr);
            sections.get(sections.size() - 1).setSectPr(sectPr);
        }
        FooterReference footerReference = objectFactory.createFooterReference();
        footerReference.setId(relationship.getId());
        footerReference.setType(HdrFtrRef.DEFAULT);
        sectPr.getEGHdrFtrReferences().add(footerReference);
    }
```

Please help me out in finding where it is going wrong.

Comment: Post the resulting docx somewhere?

Comment: @JasonPlutext.. Find it here... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LsSofAyHCb3hGi5n-3PgO8WgGElyDcyN

Comment: @JasonPlutext... Please help if you are able to find the issue...or suggest any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docx starts with:

```
<w:body>
    <w:sectPr>
        <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId4"/>
    </w:sectPr>
```

and ends with:

```
    <w:sectPr>
        <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId5"/>
```

Try moving w:headerReference from the sectPr at the beginning (which makes little sense) to the one at the end.

But according to Word 2016, the docx you posted is broken, so it has other issues which need to be addressed.

Comment: thanks @JasonPlutext it is working now...Can you please provide some steps where I can debug the broken part..FYI I am importing the html file to create the docx..

Comment: Around table 21 you have:             <w:tr>
                <w:tc/>
            </w:tr>
            <w:tbl>
                <w:tblPr/>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:tc/>
                </w:tr>
                <w:tbl>
                    <w:p>  (empty tc, improperly nested tables, and a misplaced tblPr element).   Deleting from <w:tblPr/> just before  <w:tr>
                <w:tc/>
            </w:tr> through to  </w:tbl>
            </w:tbl> (ie delete the tr containing empty tc, then the 2 nested tables) and it works

Comment: ps, if this structure was produced by Import-XHTML operating on your XHTML, please send it to me.  I'd like to handle it better.

Comment: Hi @JasonPlutext..Yes output was produce by docx4j automatically..but there was some misleading in HTML Table tags and other tags aswell in XHTML..So i fixed it at xhtml level and now it is producing the perfect output.. Thanks for your support..